# Shimano Nexus 3 stuck on lowest gear

Tags: shimano, gears, nexus

I have a bike with Shimano Nexus 3 gear, and it's stuck on lowest gear. However, if I move shift pin that changes gears it changes the gears. So Nexus itself seems to be working, but the pin is not returning to correct position when going to higher gear. Is there a spring broken that should return the pin to correct position, and if so, how should I fix it? New spring? New wheel? Lot's of WD-40?

Comment: So it sounds like you are saying the shifter may be broken.  When you manually move the pin it works, does the shifter move the pin as it should?

Comment: If I set the pin to 3rd gear, I can use the shifter to change to second but not up, and from second gear I can go to first, but not up. Shifter seems to be working but pin is not returning up

Comment: So it sounds like either your shifter or bell crank is the problem.  If you disconnect the shifter and the cable moves properly both directions while shifting, it's the bell crank, if not, then the shifter/cable/housing.

Comment: Comment for next generations: Description is unclear. Pin should return when going to LOWER gear in this hub. Its stuck, but shifts... strange.

Comment: ... If the internal spring would be broken, you probably won't be able to change gear from 3 to 2 once it was turned on (and, form 2 to 1 it wolud be even less possible). Problem with shifter is unclear - maybe its shifter suitable for Sachs Dreigang? WD-40 is good for test, but after all there is need to disassembly hub and grease it, because it is a solvent for grease.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Bell crank on the end of the axle is worn. Replace the shifter housing on the end of the axle. When worn, it won't push far enough on the shift rod. Cheap fix.